# Jena: Nullpointer exception while iterating the dataset

Tags: java, tomcat7, jena, triplestore

Can you please help me solving the below issue. I'm running the triplestore on one tomcat server and the application to access the triplestore on another tomcat7 server. For the first time, the application runs successfully however if I restart the application and not the triplestore causing the nullpointer issue.

Below is the exception causing on triplestore server

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ServletAdaptor] in context with path [/triplestore] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.util.NodeUtils$1.accept(NodeUtils.java:
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.util.NodeUtils$1.accept(NodeUtils.java:91)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.MapFilterIterator.hasNext(MapFilterIterator.java:55)
    at au.com.triplestore.core.impl.TripleStoreImpl.saveDataset(TripleStoreImpl.java:224)
    at au.com.triplestore.web.TripleStoreRs.saveData(TripleStoreRs.java:323)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org .apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

And here is the code where it fails (line is - while (listOfSavedNames.hasNext()) { )

```
public Boolean saveDataset(Model model, String baseUri, Boolean isSave, String reasonerName) {

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);        

    Boolean alreadySaved = false;

    InfModel infModel = null;

    if (baseUri == null) {
        baseUri = model.getNsPrefixURI("ex");
    }

    Iterator<String> listOfSavedNames = dataset.listNames();

    while (listOfSavedNames.hasNext()) { 
        if (baseUri.equals(listOfSavedNames.next())) {
            alreadySaved = true;
            break;
        }
    }


    if (isSave) {
        if (alreadySaved) {

            Model defaultModel = dataset.getDefaultModel();
            Model namedModel = dataset.getNamedModel(baseUri);
            dataset.removeNamedModel(baseUri);



            defaultModel.add(infModel);
            namedModel.add(infModel);
            //Add new model
            dataset.addNamedModel(baseUri, namedModel);

        } else {

            Model defaultModel = dataset.getDefaultModel();
            defaultModel.add(infModel);
            dataset.addNamedModel(baseUri, infModel);
        }
    } else {
        Model defaultModel = dataset.getDefaultModel();
        Model namedModel = dataset.getNamedModel(baseUri);
        dataset.removeNamedModel(baseUri);
        defaultModel.add(infModel);
        namedModel.add(infModel);
        //Add new model
        dataset.addNamedModel(baseUri, namedModel);
    }

    dataset.commit();
    TDB.sync(dataset);
    dataset.end();
    schemaDataset.end();
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Sure, you got a null reference somewhere and tried to access its members.  To be more helpful, we'll need to see some more code, and more other context, too.

Comment: However, issues like "For the first time, the application runs successfully however if I restart the application and not the triplestore causing the nullpointer issue." come up sometimes if the dataset gets corrupted when you're supposed to be using a dataset transactionally and you're not.

Comment: Duplicate: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/28872/jena-nullpointer-exception-while-iterating-the-dataset

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for your comments. I've included the code and the line where it is throwing nullPointerException. And I'm executing the dataset transactionally